# PayPal Advanced hosted checkout not honoring NOSHIPPING option

Tags: paypal

I have a site that is using PayPal Advanced with Layout C, where it uses an iframe to present payment options for either paying with PayPal, or entering a credit card number and paying. When clicking the Checkout with PayPal button, it goes to a payment page on PayPal. It seems that PayPal must be doing some testing of a new checkout process, because I am randomly receiving one of two different screens (shown below).

Up until recently, I've been seeing and testing with Checkout Page A. I have been sending my transactions without a shipping address, using the NOSHIPPING parameter to tell PayPal that's okay. All was good. Now, with Checkout Page B, it gives me an error when I don't send the shipping address:

```
Field format error: 10727-The field Shipping Address1 is required
```

If I go ahead and send an address, then all works fine. Anybody know why this new page is not honoring the NOSHIPPING parameter? As I said, it's exactly the same transaction details/process for both pages -- it's PayPal who is deciding which process to show me as a user on a random basis.

**Checkout page A:**

[image]

**Checkout page B:**

[image: New Checkout Page]

Details of Secure Token request:

```
USER[7]=xxxxxxx&VENDOR[8]=xxxxxxxx&PARTNER[6]=PayPal&PWD[15]=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&CREATESECURETOKEN[1]=Y&SECURETOKENID[32]=62afb751dead4d2abf191c5226dd8f21&TRXTYPE[1]=S&NOSHIPPING[1]=1&ALLOWNOTE[1]=0&INVNUM[17]=ST-BATCH-23-C8903&USER1[4]=xxxx&USER6[2]=xx&USER5[4]=xxxx&AMT[5]=30.52&BILLTOFIRSTNAME[4]=John&BILLTOLASTNAME[8]=Doexxxxx&ERRORURL[46]=**myurl**&RETURNURL[46]=**myurl**&CANCELURL[46]=**myurl**&SILENTPOSTURL[50]=**myurl**&URLMETHOD[4]=POST&
```

Details of response to my RETURNURL after logging into PayPal with my paypal account to make a payment:

```
AVSZIP=N&TYPE=S&BILLTOEMAIL=**myemail**&BILLTOLASTNAME=Doe&BILLTONAME=John&LASTNAME=Doe&PNREF=EUYPC2C6821D&TENDER=P&EMAIL=**myemail**&METHOD=P&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=John&AMT=30.52&TRANSTIME=2014-08-28+12%3a51%3a33&INVOICE=ST-BATCH-23-C8903&NAMETOSHIP=JOh+Doe&USER5=xxxx&BILLTOCOUNTRY=US&RESPMSG=Field+format+error%3a+10727-The+field+Shipping+Address1+is+required&COUNTRY=US&TAX=0.00&FIRSTNAME=John&AVSDATA=NNN&USER6=xxxx&SECURETOKEN=QpJEHzD0O1EGZJLoy3PAHxAEU&SECURETOKENID=62afb751dead4d2abf191c5226dd8f21&INVNUM=ST-BATCH-23-C8903&AVSADDR=N&NAME=John+Doe&USER1=xxxx&HOSTCODE=10727&RESULT=7&TRXTYPE=S
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you are having issues with the NOSHIPPING parameter when being directed through our new checkout flow. I am having issues recreating the error 10727 in my own testing. Would you please provide the API request you are using in your Secure Token call (minus any personal information)? Also, please provide a sample of one of the responses containing the 10727 error message? If you would feel more comfortable, you can file a ticket at paypal.com/MTS and we can communicate directly.

^EW

**Update**

*PayPal has resolved this issue and the NOSHIPPING parameter works as intended now.*

Comment: Hello, as this appears to be a bug, I am working to pull the related logs on our end and will be escalating the issue. Please open a ticket at paypal.com/MTS so we can track the issue appropriately. Once you have your ticket number, please leave it in the comments or tweet it at the PayPal_MTS handle and I will make sure to respond with relevant updates.

Comment: Thanks. Here's the ticket number: #140828-000350